# SonarQube 5.2 Quality gate name for module in multi modules maven project

Tags: sonarqube

Hye.

I have a multi modules project.
On the parent, I specify a new Quality Gate, which is not the default one.

On parent project dashboard, the Gality gate is correctly displayed.

[image]

On child module, the quality gate seems to be applyed, but the default one is displyed on the dashboard.

[image]

Did I miss something ?

Regards.

Etienne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, and I created [SONAR-7107](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7107) to fix it.

The most important here is that the correct quality gate is applied on the modules - which is actually the case. So this is just a UI bug.

Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: It also apply when you navigate throw files under the module. Yes, just UI bug, not a big deal.